# System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'Access is denied' in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to execute the below code on windows and get's error as :- System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'Access is denied'

```
   {
            var metricServer = new MetricServer(port: 8081);
            metricServer.Start();
   }
```

I tried the below command, but still getting the access denied error

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8081/ user=Administrators listen=yes
```

Comment: Does this server require username/ password?

Comment: Is the port already in use?  Does it work with a higher port number?  Maybe a firewall issue?  Can you temporarily disable any firewall and try again?